# Different colors in title page and frame title with Focus Beamer theme

Tags: beamer, color

I'm using the Focus theme for Beamer, and I'd like to have a custom background color for the title page (+ the section pages), and a *different* color in the headers and footers of individual slides: say a nice dark red for the title page, and a more neutral grey for the slides.

I am able to change the color of the footer, but not the header, see code below. I would expect something like \setbeamercolor{frametitle} or \setbeamercolor{headline} would do the trick, but the former changes colors everywhere (i.e., also on the title page) while the latter does nothing.

Any tips short of going into the .sty files?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{focus}
\definecolor{main}{RGB}{141, 2, 31} % dark red
\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=black!60}
% \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black!60}
% \setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=black!60}

\title{Title Page}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Hello!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Produces this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the focus theme does not provide any tools to change these colours independently, so one needs to resort to a bit of violence against the theme:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{focus}
\definecolor{main}{RGB}{141, 2, 31} % dark red
\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=black!60}
% \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black!60}
% \setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=black!60}


\setbeamercolor{mycolor}{bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\let\beamer@@tmpop@frametitle@focus\undefined
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{focus}{%
    % If not title page.
    \ifnum\value{realframenumber}>0%
        \vspace{-1pt}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=0.55cm,rightskip=0.55cm,sep=0.2cm]{mycolor}%
            \strut\insertframetitle\strut%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \fi%
}

\makeatother

\title{Title Page}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Hello!
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{section}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    content...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]